# How does GitHub guess the encoding of a file?

Tags: github, character-encoding

How GitHub guesses encoding of a text file?

I have two text files in [my repository](https://github.com/anton-petrunin/mpman-ru): [README.ru.koi8-r](https://github.com/anton-petrunin/mpman-ru/blob/master/README.ru.koi8-r) and [mpman-ru.tex](https://github.com/anton-petrunin/mpman-ru/blob/master/mpman-ru.tex),
both use encoding koi8-r. GitHub uses right encoding for the first one and uses wrong for the second one.

Maybe there is a trick to force right guess?

**Postscript.** I solved the problem by adding a long comment at the top of the file in koi8-r, but there should be a better way to do it.

Comment: Interestingly both Ruby's `rchardet` and JavaScripts `jschardet` get this right. I thought for sure one of those libraries would be at fault.

Answer (score 2):

In the [GitHub documentation](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/wiki/Git-Encoding) it is stated that you in fact should "determine encoding for every single file". Furthermore they say that "(...) encoding could be set in .gitattributes file." which is probably what you are looking for right now as this will be pushable to GitHub ([documentation for gitattributes files on git-scm](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes)).

Comment: I added line "*.tex text working-tree-encoding=koi8-r" to .gitattributes file, but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You set the encoding for a repository with

`git config gui.encoding koi8-r`

Comment: It solves the problem locally, but changes nothing on GitHub.